# MongoDB Compass - How To Insert Date Type?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

When inserting a document into a MongoDB database with MongoDB Compass how do I insert the current date?

I have tried like so:

[image]

But as you can see there is an error.

How do I insert the current date using MongoDB Compass?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try like this:

```
2016-01-24T13:21:55.000
```

Answer (score 22):

Try like this:

```
{
"type":"grunt",
"last_used": {
        "$date": "2018-04-15T16:54:40.000Z"
    },
"created_at": {
        "$date": "2018-04-15T16:54:40.000Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```json
{
"type": "grunt",
"last_used": {"$date":{"$numberLong":"1602720972129"}},
"created_at":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1602720972129"}}
}
```